# Unable to stat SSHFS mount unless root

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, sshfs

Does anyone understand why the `nobody` user is having trouble `stat`-ing the `foo` directory, when it definitely has execute permissions? It seems like there are some permissions I'm unaware of at this point. I’ve chmod `777`’ed the folder at this point, but even then `nobody` cannot `stat` it.

#### Showing that `foo` is `777` and owned by `nobody`:

```
$ sudo ls -l                                                                                                                                                                                          [sudo] password for hamiltont:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 17 23:05 completed
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 17 23:05 config
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 17 19:55 foo
```

#### Showing that nobody cannot `stat` `foo`:

```
$ sudo su nobody                                                                                                                                                                                      nobody@ht-media:/lxc/sonarr$ ls -l
ls: cannot access foo: Permission denied
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 17 23:05 completed
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 17 23:05 config
d????????? ? ?      ?          ?            ? foo
```

The mount command is nothing special, just mount remote folder `~` from machine `foo` into `/folder/foo` as `uid=nobody` and `gid=nogroup`

```
sshfs -o uid=$(id -u nobody) -o gid=$(getent group nogroup | cut -d: -f3) foo:~ /folder/foo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this answer on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59695), it seems like you should use the `allow_other` option when initially mounting with SSHFS. So your command which looks like this now:

```
sshfs -o uid=$(id -u nobody) -o gid=$(getent group nogroup | cut -d: -f3) foo:~ /folder/foo
```

Should be changed to:

```
sshfs -o allow_other uid=$(id -u nobody) -o gid=$(getent group nogroup | cut -d: -f3) foo:~ /folder/foo
```